# How to get url of Product image field of Entity Reference field

Tags: 7, commerce, entities

Trying to create a view (a block) with associated products on product pages. Products have a field "Related products" (Entity Reference) and in my view (show products' fields) I can get images and titles of them using contextual filter (Content: Nid) and relationship (Entity Reference: Related products). But there's a problem with the url of titles and images, they're leading to editing pages (like admin/commerce/products/1), but not to content.
I tried to add a field Content:Path, but I get a link to a product itself, not to related with it products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're creating your view, you need one more relationship. Look for this relationship:

> Commerce Product: Referencing Node
>
> (Relate a product to the Node referencing it through field_product.)

This will allow you to harness the "reverse-relationship" going from the product to the reverse-node. Add this relationship, require it, and then use this to generate your links.

Comment: Don't know how could I miss this relationship. It works! Thank you, nvahalik!